# GAE: whether to migrate to ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I understand that ndb offers a number of features that improve on the regular db, and I would like to eventually take advantage of those new features.

Will the current db eventually include the features of ndb so that I won't ever need to migrate to ndb?

Or, will the current db be deprecated so that I will eventually have to migrate to ndb?

If the former, then I can be patient, but if the latter, I would rather get the migration over with sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider ndb as the successor of the current db. So, if the features of ndb suit your needs, I would propose to migrate to the new scheme.

Comment: Why do you consider that?  Would be nice to have some info from Google on this.

Comment: @Kekito Based on the comparison of the two technologies and since ndb is presented as an improved version of db. Of course, I totally agree with you that Google should provide some information about that in order to be totally clear.

Comment: I apologize we have not been sufficiently aggressive in promoting NDB as db's replacement.  You should definitely consider it the planned replacement for db, and soon we will be promoting it officially.

Answer (score 0):

Before migration please have look into it [DB vs NDB](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic)

Because potentially needed some programming changes too.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but that is good info to know.